# How to setup long code through programming way in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In our application We have multiple firm setup and Within the firm, there are multiple users. So We want two way communication between firm number and user's number. In this, Whenever User registers a firm, we have to setup firm's phone number as long codes on Twilio account through programming way so that this firm can use this phone number for sending or receiving sms to/from firm's user. How can we do it in Twilio? Please provide specific link or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Evangelist here.

Check out the [Phone Numbers API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/) docs.

The AvailablePhoneNumbers resource lets you [search for phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/available-phone-numbers#search-and-buy-phone-numbers):

```
curl -G https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/Local.json \
    -d "AreaCode=510" \
    -u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
```

the IncomingPhoneNumbers resource lets you [purchase phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incoming-phone-numbers#create-an-incomingphonenumber-resource):

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IncomingPhoneNumbers.json \
    --data-urlencode "FriendlyName=My Company Line" \
    --data-urlencode "PhoneNumber=+15105647903" \
    --data-urlencode "VoiceMethod=GET" \
    --data-urlencode "VoiceUrl=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml" \
    -u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token
```

and [update purchased phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incoming-phone-numbers#update-an-incomingphonenumber-resource):

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PN2a0747eba6abf96b7e3c3ff0b4530f6e.json \
    --data-urlencode "AccountSid=ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
    --data-urlencode "SmsUrl=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/sms.xml" \
    --data-urlencode "VoiceUrl=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml" \
    -u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token
```

Hope that helps.